# Handling Connection Strings for Many Applications

Tags: vb.net, connection-string

I've been maintaining and developing .NET apps for my company for a couple years now. It seems that the programmers before me did not have a perfect solution for handling connection strings to our different databases. Program A has the connection strings hard-coded, Program B has the connection strings saved in the project settings, and Program C pulls the connection strings from a database table.

What is the best way to handle common connection strings between many different applications?

Comment: Where does Program C store its connection string to get to the database containing the connection strings?

Comment: Program C uses a DSN file to connect to the database table which holds the other connection strings.

Comment: When you say common connection strings what do you mean. That many applications use the same connection string? Usually the best practice is for each application to store the connection string in a .config file.